# jws in glassfish without acc. (depl from eclipse)

Tags: java, glassfish, java-web-start, sign, acc

I want to make a java swing client available by Java Web Start. Glassfish does this automatically (generates a jnlp and signs the required jars). My problem is that the Glassfish generated jnlp also includes all the application client container stuff that comes with a large footprint.

How can i deploy the client app smoothly from Eclipse? I realise one way is serving the jnlp with a servlet, building and signing the jars manualy and put them in webcontent folder of the .war, then deploy the war.

Comment: *"application client container stuff"*  What is that, exactly?

Comment: The packages used for accessing ejbs jndi lookup jms etc. My client doesnt use any of it

Comment: I would guess (don't use it) Glassfish has some way to configure what is/is not added to an app. Look further into the Glassfish docs. before turning to the IDE for deployment.

Comment: I think all the files necessary to support a JNLP app can be can be treated as static content on a server... so you do not need to create a custom web app to support your swing client.  So, you should be able to create the jnlp file and the jars that it references and place them all on the server in the docroot (or some place similar)

Comment: Your aprouch will work vkraemer, but it will not utilize the automatic .jar signing done by glassfish afaik.

Comment: Andrew, ive read the jnlp customization documents for glassfish a bit. But as understand it, it only allows for appending additional resources. But i will have to try it at next opurtunity

Comment: i ended up using kraemers sugestion and simply added the jars in webcontent folder. side effect being i learned alot about ant,maven and jws.